# PHP include path: what am I doing wrong?

Tags: php, path, include

OK I'm quite sure this is the easiest question someone out there will ever answer.

I try to get and echo the contents of a file in the same level:

```
die(file_get_contents('test.txt')); //"hello"
```

Works fine. I try to invalidate that call by setting a bad include path:

```
set_include_path('non-existant-dir');
die(file_get_contents('test.txt')); //still "hello"
```

...but it still finds the file. Shouldn't `set_include_path` [mean](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.include-path) the call to `file_get_contents` looks for `test.txt` in a dir called `non-existant-dir`, and thus fail?

Comment: It's very well possible that you've set up your include path in your Apache config file (or .htaccess). This will override `set_include_path()`. Comment out any "php_value include_path" type lines in your Apache conf file, and you should be able to set it now in your php code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `php.ini` config look for `include_path` which overrides the `set_include_path` function and commment it out then restart apache.

Comment: Thanks. One wonders what the point of `set_include_path()` is, then!

Answer (score 3):

The function "file_get_contents" can take several arguments - one of which is a combination of flags where one such flag is "FILE_USE_INCLUDE_PATH" - by default I don't think it will use the include path so it makes no difference what you set the include path to.
Try:

```
set_include_path('non-existant-dir');
die( file_get_contents('test.txt', FILE_USE_INCLUDE_PATH) );
```

Comment: Tried but still seems to find the file!

Comment: Initially I had the "FILE_USE_INCLUDE_PATH" in the wrong place - but I notice that if the file is in the same directory as the script running this code it finds the file regardless. I believe that is due, as @Mihai notes, the default values in php.ini. For example, on Windows the include path might be include_path=".;c:\php\includes" so it looks first at '.' - current directory!